# Creating a local storage score

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to store a players score in local storage, here's the code:

```
<script>
window.onload = checkScore();

function checkScore() {
    score = localStorage.getItem("score");
    if (score == null || score == "null") {
        score = a;
        localStorage.setItem("score", score);
    } else {
        a += score;
    }
}
</script>
```

`a` is the variable for points in my game btw.

Comment: What is the question? What is not working?

Comment: I dont know why it isnt working

Comment: It just says score is undefined

Comment: Can you give more detail? Starting with what is/isn't working? I think you should display the rest of your javascript (Related/Relevant). I would also recommend you check your browser console for errors. If this is the full javascript source code, you need to declare your variables **Tip:** `var score=`

Answer (score 1):

A couple of issues there:

1. Since the things you get from local storage are always strings, if you want to treat `score` like a number, you'll want to convert it via `score = Number(score)`, `score = +score`, or `parseInt(score, 10)` as appropriate to your use case.
2. You're adding `score` to `a`; I'd think you wanted to add `a` to `score`.
3. Yuo're never storing the updated `score` if it was there to start with, only if you added it fresh.
4. The window `load` event happens **very** late in the page load process, waiting for all images and other external resources to load. That's likely far too late for this.
5. If you *did* want to use the `load` event, `window.onload = checkScore();` doesn't do it. That *calls* `checkScore` and assigns its return value to `window.onload`, exactly the way `x = foo()` *calls* `foo` and assigns its return value to `x`. You'd want `window.onload = checkScore;` (no `()`).
6. Your code is falling prey to [*The Horror Of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) by not declaring `score` (unless you declare it somewhere you haven't shown).

Minimal updates:

In a `script` tag at the end of the document:

```
function checkScore(){
    var score = +(localStorage.getItem("score") || 0); // Easier way to initialize it
    score += a;
    localStorage.setItem("score", score);
} 
checkScore();
```

I'm not sure if you wanted to update `a` or not (I know there was code to do it in the question, but...). And I don't know where `a` comes from, so can't help with whether you're using it right.

Comment: var a = 0;
 function checkScore(){
    var score = (localStorage.getItem("score") || 0); // Easier way to initialize it
 if (score >= 1) {
  alert("hi");
  score += a;
  a += score;
  document.getElementById("2").innerHTML = a;
  localStorage.setItem("score", score);
  }
  if (score <= 0) {
  score += a;
  localStorage.setItem("score", score);
  }
 
 
 }

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = 0;
function checkScore(){
var score = (localStorage.getItem("score") || 0); // Easier way to initialize it
if (score >= 1) {
    alert("hi");
    score += a;
    a += score;
    document.getElementById("2").innerHTML = a;
    localStorage.setItem("score", score);
    }
    if (score <= 0) {
    score += a;
    localStorage.setItem("score", score);
    }


}
```

Comment: This still isnt working di like ome more help please this is my new code